# Django - custom 403 template

Tags: python, django, templates, http-status-code-403, django-csrf

I'm trying to use my 403, 404, 500 custom templates in Django 1.5 .
404 and 500 work perfectly, but 403 still showing me the built-in Django 403 template.

I put all three templates in the root template directory in my project.
They are named : 403.html, 404.html, 500.html

I also tried using:

urls.py:

```
 from django.utils.functional import curry
 handler403 = curry(permission_denied, template_name='403.html')
```

and also:
urls.py:

```
handler403 = 'proj_name.views.my_custom_permission_denied_view'
```

proj_name/views.py

```
def my_custom_permission_denied_view(request):
    return ethoos_response('403.html', None, request)
```

Both methods do not work. Also in 404 and 500 I use none of these methods, just the templates inside the template directory, and they are shown.

All three suppose to work the same way according to Django's documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

I have no idea why only 403 doesn't.
Thanks.

Comment: Works for me, there should be no requirement to overwrite any code. What's your exact django version, what does your template setting look like, have you put a breakpoint in the 403 handler to see what is going on?

Comment: my Django.version is (1, 5, 0, 'final', 0) .
I have not yet breakpointed the handler.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using Django 1.5 ? in two weeks time, it would have been unsupported for a full year https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: The latest docs for the 403 handler in django are here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For regular 403 permission denied pages, creating the `403.html` template should work.

However, for CSRF errors (which also return status code 403), you should create a `403_csrf.html` template instead.

Creating a `403_csrf.html` template works in Django 1.10+. For earlier versions, you had to change the [`CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#csrf-failure-view) setting to the view you want to use.

See the [CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#rejected-requests) for more info.

There was [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/O2raF0RVGA0/44-3Jz0jCwAJ) about why the CSRF failure  view behaves differently in the Django-developers mailing list this week.

Comment: Thank you! that was it.
I also recommend on this solution example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925244/django-how-to-override-the-csrf-failure-template

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `403_csrf.html`.