# How to add custom page for 403 error django

Tags: python, django

Question as in title. How to set custom page for an error in django. I tried using just in templates new file like `'403.html'` but it did not work.
I tried also this:

```
def handler404(request, exception, template_name="404.html"):
    response = render_to_response(template_name)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

but I can not import render_to_response

Answer (score 0):

There are two different versions of a 403 error, one is specifically for CSRF issues.

You may need to use a template named `403_csrf.html` in addition to `403.html`

More information can be found at the following links:

- [Django - custom 403 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981239/django-custom-403-template)
- [Django : How to override the CSRF_FAILURE_TEMPLATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925244/django-how-to-override-the-csrf-failure-template)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#csrf-failure-view
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/eba9a9b7f72995206af867600d6685b5405f172a/django/views/csrf.py#L101