# How can I get a detailed log of django csrf failure?

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I am troubleshooting a Django app.

Recently the app seems to *Randomly* generate CSRF verification errors:

`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`
(Resulting in a 403)

**Where can I find detailed information on the cause of the verification failure?**

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting the log to show. It will only know that the CSRF token was not present in the POST.

Comment: That error presents even when a token is present, but not the expected / valid token.  Information about the cause of failure would be useful (if it exists).

Comment: Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925244/django-how-to-override-the-csrf-failure-template . It helped me out.

Comment: Hello Dan, did you find any good solution to debug CSRF errors? Im having sporadic CSRF problems with AJAX and I dont know how to debug them cause I can't reproduce them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is on the client side - which won't by default know what's going wrong on your server unless you have set `DEBUG = True` (which you don't want to do in production).

If it was replicable on your staging server it would be easy to fix, since you could replicate the error with `DEBUG = True` on staging and quickly see where the verification fails in Django's `csrf.py`.

What you're looking for is the output of [which of these error is occurring on your server](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L25).

If you [implement logging in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/) you'll be able to investigate and determine which of these errors was triggered on your production site. A service like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) makes this even simpler since it will send you the traceback anytime an error happens.